# Implementing default item in GTK 3.0/Rust Combobox

Tags: rust

So I am trying to implement a dropdown with GTK 3.0/Rust Combobox.

https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/class.ComboBox.html#methods

I have the UI with the downwards facing chevron typical of a dropdown menu but I need to get just one default item in there to display and I have not been successful in understanding how to do so with the docs available in the wild.

This instance method of `set_active_id` is the only one rust-analyzer has not complained about:

```
.combo_box("dropdown")
  .with_combo_box(|combobox| {
    combobox.set_active_id(Some("gibberish"));
  })
.end("dropdown")
```

However, I am unable to see "gibberish" as an item in the dropdown.